# php code not working the same in all browsers

Tags: php

i hear many times that PHP code working the same in all browsers
but in my case there is difference ... for example ...

and when i download the file from safari it have extension and download normally

[when download from safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To2uT.png)

but when i download using chrome, the extension of the file disappear and unknown file downloading ...

[when download from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHhmV.png)

and explanation please ??

and i used below code for downloading file ... that work in safari but not in chrome ....

```
<?php
// Make sure an ID was passed
if(isset($_GET['download_id'])) {
// Get the ID
    $id = intval($_GET['download_id']);

    // Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
    if($id <= 0) {
        die('The ID is invalid!');
    }
    else {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', '*****', '*****', '*******');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }
 
        // Fetch the file information
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE id=$id";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $sql);
        
     $filepath =  $row['code'];
 
        if($result) {
            // Make sure the result is valid
            if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            // Get the row
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                // Print headers
                
header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('images/' .$row['name']));           
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($row['code']));
readfile('images/' . $row['name']);

            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! No File exists with that ID.';
            }
        header("Refresh:0");
            // Free the mysqli resources
            @mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
        mysqli_close($dbLink);
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
}

?>
```

Comment: What are the HTTP headers you are returning for those images? How are you embedding these images in HTML. Unless you are generating the images with PHP, I doubt this is a PHP issue.

Comment: Are the photos (which cannot be displayed in chrome) located in the webserver serving the PHP page ? (or are the photos located in a different machine ?)

Comment: it located in the webserver serving the PHP page .

Comment: @Evert i use image src for calling image

Comment: @aidelakreyi  share the _exact_ image tag as it appears in the HTML. Edit your question, don't comment. And share the exact set of HTTP headers for those images.

Comment: <img src='./images/ ???? can you use <img src='/images/

Comment: @BookOfZeus , yes i can but it don't upload the image (ie. do nothing)

Comment: Use your browser's dev-tools to inspect those `<img>` tags. Compare the `src` properties as far as the browser has interpreted it. Also check the _Network_ panel to see what URLs are being requested for those images

Comment: try removing spaces from src='./images/<?php  echo $row['code'

Comment: sorry dear @Phil I’m having trouble understanding your explanation , and what makes me can't understand is (why its working normally and without any problems in safari , but not in chrome ) and i tried chrome from other laptops , but still the same problem ....

Comment: [Chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) / [Safari dev tools](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/). I wasn't explaining anything, I was telling you to use developer tools to try and figure out what's wrong

Comment: dear @HossamMaher i removed the spaces but still the same problem ... thanx for your help

Comment: dear @Phil i used it and it gives the correct name and path of the file .but still can't display .. i edited my post and if you can please look at it i will be thankful

Comment: `.pdf` files are not images

Comment: yes dear @Phil i mentioned in my post that my files are PDFs

Comment: You cannot `readfile` and `echo`, it is one or the other, you can’t do two things, that’s not how HTTP works

Comment: Specifically, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php, which shows a bunch of other things you're also going to have to address if you want to use readFile

Comment: Have you tried putting the filename inside the Content-Disposition header into double quotes yet? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#examples